# Hexagon button with lines CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm trying to create component similar to image.[image]

But I can't find the way how can I can style the button and this block in css.
What I have now.

```css
.button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background: transparent;
    width: 390px;
    height: 72px;
    line-height: 80px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1C1C21;
    margin: 40px auto;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button:before,
.button:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 390px;
    left: 0;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.button:before {
    transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(3deg);
}
.button:after {
    top: 40px;
    transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(-3deg);
}

/* Button Border Style */

.button.border:before,
.button.border:after {
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D8;
}
.button.border:before {
    border-bottom: none; /* to prevent the border-line showing up in the middle of the shape */
}
.button.border:after {
    border-top: none; /* to prevent the border-line showing up in the middle of the shape */
}

.button-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
<a href="#" class="button ribbon-outset border">Click me! </a>
<a href="#" class="button ribbon-outset border">Click me! </a>
<a href="#" class="button ribbon-outset border">Click me! </a>
<a href="#" class="button ribbon-outset border">Click me! </a>
</div>
```

But it's not similar to what I want.
How can I do this element button and the how I can display them like on image and for mobile devices to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background images are the way to go for this. If your buttons are a fixed size that’s easy, but if you need them to be flexible width you can use a stack of three images, one each for the left and right sides, on top of a repeating centre section.

[image: diagram of arrangement of suggested background images]

```css
.button-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px 0;
}

.button-wrapper a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background-image: url(https://donald.au/bugs/so-77147160/button-left.svg), url(https://donald.au/bugs/so-77147160/button-right.svg), url(https://donald.au/bugs/so-77147160/button.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;
  background-position: 0%, 100%, 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <a href="#">Click me!</a>
  <a href="#">Click me!</a>
  <a href="#">Click me!</a>
  <a href="#">Click me many times!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.It's definitely what I want.Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea would need to refining and playing around with to get right but you could also try using pseudo elements to accomplish this.

```css
.hex-btn {
    position: relative;
    
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    
    background-color: red;
    
    border-radius: 5px;
    
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}


.hex-btn::after {
    content: "";
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: -8%;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    
    background-color: red;
    
    border-radius: 3px;
    
    transform: rotate(45deg);
} 


.hex-btn::before {
    content: "";
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    right: -8%;
    
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    
    background-color: red;
    
    border-radius: 3px;
    
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="hex-btn">Hex BTN</div>
```

[image]